# At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement search implementation with filter using search framework:

```
@GetMapping("find")
    public Page<MerchantUserDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                @Spec(path = "name", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "login", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "email", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
        }) Specification<Users> specification,
            @SortDefault(sort = "login", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return merchantUserService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)
                .map(g -> MerchantUserDTO.builder()                   
                        .id(g.getId())
                        .login(g.getLogin())                        
                        .build()
                );
    }

@Override
    public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
        return dao.findAllByTypeIn(specification, pageable, "MerchantUser");
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MerchantUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users> {

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable, String... types);
}
```

But I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue when I have a defined specification?

Comment: yes, the above code is the problem. When I use `dao.findAll(specification, pageable);` it's working fine.

Comment: how are you building the `Specification<Users>` parameter being passed in?

Comment: Here is the code example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948257/implement-specification-with-in-clause

Comment: @PeterPenzov Where is the example code?