# Add WHERE IN clause to JPA Specification

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to implement search functionality limited by IN clause:

I want to implement search implementation with filter limitation:

```
    @GetMapping("find")
    public Page<MerchantUserDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                @Spec(path = "name", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "login", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                @Spec(path = "email", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
            }) Specification<Users> specification,
            @SortDefault(sort = "login", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return merchantUserService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)
                .map(g -> MerchantUserDTO.builder()                   
                        .id(g.getId())
                        .login(g.getLogin())                        
                        .build()
                );
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
        return dao.findAllByTypeIn(specification, pageable, "MerchantUser");
    }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MerchantUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users> {

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable, String... types);
}
```

What is the proper way to extend the specification with IN clause?

`specification.and(path.in(types))` path is a attribute but how to implement it properly?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you need help with?

Comment: @JensSchauder The above Specification works fine but I want to limit all SELECT clauses with IN clause (WHERE type IN ('MerchantUser')). How I can add this clause into the specification? Can you give me some code sample how to do it?

Comment: @JensSchauder I also tried this but it's not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942688/at-least-2-parameters-provided-but-only-1-parameters-present-in-query

Comment: Show us what you tried and how it is failing.

Comment: @JensSchauder I have tried the above code. Here is the error stack: https://pastebin.com/WJrJRC01

Comment: Is there some way to restrict the queries with IN clause using specification?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally this can be achieved this way:

1. Create specification implementation

```java
    public class MerchantUserSpecification implements Specification<Users> {
    
        private final List<String> types;
    
        public MerchantUserSpecification(List<String> types) {
            this.types = types;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Users> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            if (types != null && !types.isEmpty()) {
                return root.get(Users_.type).in(types);
            } else {
                // always-true predicate, means that no filtering would be applied
                return cb.and(); 
            }
        }
```

2. Use method [Page findAll(@Nullable Specification spec, Pageable pageable);](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) inherited from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface instead of using your custom `findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification....)`

```java
    @Override
    public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
        // combine original specification (passed from outside) and filter-by-types specification
        Specification<Users> finalSpec = Specification.where(specification)
               .and(new MerchantUserSpecification(Arrays.asList("MerchantUser")))
        return dao.findAll(finalSpec, pageable)
    }
```

**P.S.**

With Java 8+ and for simple cases (like yours) the code may be reduced even more. Instead of implementing `Specification<T>` in separate class you can just create a method

```
private Specification<Users> typeIn(List<String> types) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        if (types != null && !types.isEmpty()) {
           return root.get(Users_.type).in(types);
        } else {
           // always-true predicate, means that no filtering would be applied
           return cb.and(); 
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
    // combine original specification (passed from outside) and filter-by-types specification
    Specification<Users> finalSpec = Specification.where(specification)
            .and(typeIn(Arrays.asList("MerchantUser")))
    return dao.findAll(finalSpec, pageable)
}
```

**UPDATE: Shortest way**

```
@Override
public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
    // combine original specification (passed from outside) and filter-by-types specification
    Specification<Users> finalSpec = Specification.where(specification)
            .and((root, query, cb) -> root.get(Users_.type).in(Arrays.asList("MerchantUser"))
    return dao.findAll(finalSpec, pageable)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Just in case is there some other way that you can show me with much more simple code?

Comment: @PeterPenzov i'm not aware of shorter way

Comment: @PeterPenzov Null & emptiness check of `types` collection might be removed to shorten the code, if you are sure that it will always be non-empty

Comment: One question. Where did you get `Users_`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov it's a metamodel class for `Users` entity class. It's generated by Hibernate processor. Details here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: I use JPA. I get `Users_ cannot be resolved to a variable` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Follow the link, it's written there how to launch Hibernate processor during maven build. After re-build missing classes should appear

Comment: I tried to configure it but I get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290897/configure-hibernate-jpamodelgen-in-maven

Comment: Do I need to create manually Users_ when I add hibernate-jpamodelgen into the POM file?

Comment: I created manually User_. But I get No property type found for type User!" during package deployment.

Comment: I agree but  hibernate-jpamodelgen is not generating any classes. Any idea why? Here is my POM file: https://pastebin.com/pUZLP7F4

Comment: Finally I managed to fix the issue but I get null value at this line: 'Specification<Users> finalSpec = specification
            .and((root, query, cb) -> root.get(Users_.type).in(Arrays.asList("MerchantUser"))' Error stack: https://pastebin.com/9TX1C4VB

Comment: @PeterPenzov use debugger and figure out what exact expression produces NPE

Comment: I found out that Specification object is empty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322787/send-empty-search-specification Is there some way yo initialise new Specification object when it's null?

Comment: Try wrapping. `specification.and(...)` => `Specification.where(specification).and(...)`