# Configure hibernate-jpamodelgen in Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I want to configure `hibernate-jpamodelgen` into Maven `pom.xml`. I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Plugin</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
         ........
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>datalis_plugin</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.6</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>               
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>   
</project>
```

Full POM: https://pastebin.com/VjucMAYL

But I get error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project org.plugin: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Annotation processor 'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor' not found
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

I used this quite: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Which version of Java are you using ?

Comment: Latest - java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16

Answer (score 7):

I usually just add the hibernate-jpamodelgen to the annotationprocessorpath of the compiler plugin. That prevents the processor to be packaged in the deployment.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
          <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, you can use `<version>${hibernate.version}</version>` so that the version is aligned with the one that Spring Boot recommends.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add plugin

```
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
```

And then rebuild

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Comment: Thanks, yesterday I tried this but I get `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.1.0:process (execution: process, phase: generate-sources)` at line 218 here: https://pastebin.com/kRLDwa8s

Comment: Let me try to solve it by adding <pluginManagement>

Comment: Unfortunately I can build the project but again meta models are not generated. ... Very strange.....

Comment: Do I need to make some specific configuration for Spring?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
  <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

```
import com.mycompany.myapp.domain.*; // for static metamodels
import com.mycompany.myapp.domain.User

public class UserQueryService {

private Specification<User> createSpecification(UserCriteria criteria) {
  Specification<User> specification = Specification.where(null);
  if (criteria != null) {
    if (criteria.getId() != null) {
       specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getId(), User_.id));
    }
  }
  return specification;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of Java 12, use the below code snippet inside build in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>12</release>  
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After this, add the below for jpamodelgen.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What about <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>?

Comment: Looks like it's not working. I'm trying to implement this code: https://pastebin.com/GW7MxMDN I get `cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable PaymentTransactions_` probably because `PaymentTransactions_` is not generated. Do you know should I create `PaymentTransactions_` manually?

Comment: Let me check, by the way, are you able to build the project using maven command ?

Comment: using `clean package`?

Comment: It means you are able to build the project using maven command, it is about not generating the classes. Can you check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764266/generate-the-jpa-metamodel-files-using-maven-processor-plugin-what-is-a-conven

Comment: You can also check this link. https://github.com/jinahya/jpa-metamodels-with-maven-example/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: But I think it's for older Java versions?

Comment: I can confirm that the answer of @Sambit works. His configuration makes the files being generated at target/generated-sources/annotations. This can easily be overseen. The directory can be added as source folder in IDEs as eclipse. When doing so compile errors for non resolvable types in IDEs may be solved.

Comment: BTW: No other plugins or configurations are necessary for jpa static model generation!

Answer (score 1):

Adding hibernate-jpamodelgen to my dependencies did not do the job for me, but rather created dependency conflicts, which caused the dependencyConvergence of the maven-enforcer-plugin to complain unless I combined it with scope 'protected'. Besides, it does not seem plausible to me to declare a runtime dependency unless I have one.

It turned out not to be necessary for me: I used Cesar's approach, but unlike in Cesar's case, I did not need to add
hibernate-jpamodelgen or anything else to my dependencies.

I already had a processor added to the maven-compiler-plugin, namely mapstruct-processor.
Like Cesar suggested, I added the hibernate-jpamodelgen to that configuration. In my case, the result was:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
            </path>
            <!-- The following path declaration is the only thing I added to make hibernate-jpamodelgen run -->
            <path>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.20.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```