# hibernate-jpamodelgen does not generate metamodels with maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jpamodelgen

I have a Spring Boot project using maven. It uses 4 plugins for build with maven-compiler-plugin:

- **hibernate-jpamodelgen** to generate the JPA meta-model (Entity_)
- mapstruct-processor for mappers
- lombok & lombok-mapstruct-binding for getters en setters, constructors, ...

However when I use `mvn clean package` to create an executable jar, **compilation fails because metamodel classes were not generated**. Instead I get a bunch of "cannot find symbol" with the target EntityClassNames_.

Mapstruct is generating the mappers in the `target\generated-sources\annotation`, but there's nothing about metamodels. I don't understand why metamodels sources are not generated. Has anyone any clue on this? Any pom.xml working with these?

If I build the project from eclipse classes are well generated, but it does not work directly from command line with maven.

My Java version is 11, and hibernate-jpamodelgen is 5.4.29.Final

Here is the build section from my pom.xml :

```xml
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Unlike other issues I don't have error on the hibernate-jpamodelgen itself, I don't know if it is really executed or not. It looks like it is not generating the sources it should.

I tried the suggestions from [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290897/configure-hibernate-jpamodelgen-in-maven) with no luck.

I created a simple project with the same pom.xml and an entity and metamodel works.