# Send empty search specification

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@GetMapping("find")
    public Page<PaymentTransactionsDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                    @Spec(path = "unique_id", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                    @Spec(path = "merchant_id", spec = In.class),                   
                    @Spec(path = "createdAt", params = "from", spec = GreaterThanOrEqual.class, config="uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"),
                    @Spec(path = "createdAt", params = "to", spec = LessThanOrEqual.class, config="uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
            }) Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification,
            @SortDefault(sort = "createdAt", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable,
            Authentication authentication) {

        return transactionService.getAllBySpecificationByTerminalId(specification, pageable)
                  .map(g -> PaymentTransactionsDTO.builder()                      
                            .id(g.getId()) 

                            .build()
                    );       
    }
```

Implementation:

```
    @Override
    public Page<PaymentTransactions> getAllBySpecificationByTerminalId(Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification,
            Pageable pageable ) {           
        Specification<PaymentTransactions> finalSpec = specification
                .and(typeIn( ));
        return dao.findAll(finalSpec, pageable);
    }

    private Specification<PaymentTransactions> typeIn( ) {

        List<Integer> terminal_idsdd = new ArrayList<>();
        terminal_idsdd.add(45);
        terminal_idsdd.add(35); 

        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            if (terminal_idsdd != null && !terminal_idsdd.isEmpty()) {
               return root.get(PaymentTransactions_.terminalId).in(terminal_idsdd);
            } else {
               // always-true predicate, means that no filtering would be applied
               return cb.and(); 
            }
        };
    }
```

When I set default value it's working fine but the search is incorrect.

```
@Spec(path = "unique_id", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class, defaultVal="123"),
```

By default no search params are send from UI so I'm thinking to create something like empty Specification object like this:

```
@Override
        public Page<PaymentTransactions> getAllBySpecificationByTerminalId(Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification,
                Pageable pageable ) {

            if (specification == null) {
                Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification = new Specification<PaymentTransactions>();
            }

            Specification<PaymentTransactions> finalSpec = specification
                    .and(typeIn( ));
            return dao.findAll(finalSpec, pageable);
        }
```

Can you guide me how I can solve this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

I believe all the http parameters you are using are optional ( by default all http parameter are optional ). so it's obvious that specification will be null when no parameter is passed. So you need to handle this null case manually. I think your approach is right but posting a simple suggestion below. Hope you will find it helpful.

Instead of having an overhead of an empty object you can simply do this.

```
@Override
        public Page<PaymentTransactions> getAllBySpecificationByTerminalId(Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification,
                Pageable pageable ) {

            Specification<PaymentTransactions> finalSpec = null;

            if (specification == null) {
                finalSpec = typeIn();
            } else {

                finalSpec = specification
                                 .and(typeIn( ));
            }
            return dao.findAll(finalSpec, pageable);
        }
```

else

you can make some of your parameter non-optional to totally remove the chances of specification becoming null, as the client will be forced to pass those parameters.