# IllegalStateException: Operator IN on type requires a Collection argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create this Spring Data Repository:

***Repository:***

```
@Repository
public interface CustomersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users> {

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable, List<String> types);
}
```

***Service:***

```
@Override
public Page<Users> findAll(int page, int size) {
    return dao.findAllByTypeIn(PageRequest.of(page, size), "CustomerUser");
}

@Override
public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
    return this.dao.findAllByTypeIn(specification, pageable, List.of("CustomerUser"));
}
```

When I deploy the package I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operator IN on type requires a Collection argument, found interface org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification in method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.engine.plugin.production.service.CustomersRepository.findAllByTypeIn(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,java.util.List).
```

Do you know how this issue can be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `Specification` with Spring data drived query in that way. You should use `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.

`FindByTypeIn` and methods like that define derived query, it means Spring Data JPA derived the query to be executed from the name of your method, this Capability provided to your `CustomerRepository` because you extended your repository from the `JpaRepository`, on the other hand `findAll(Specification specification, Pagable pagable)` came from another interface which is `JpaSpecificationExecutor`, its Ok to extend both of these Interfaces but it does not mean you can mix and match their Capability together:

So you Should define your repository like below and you should omit methods that contains Specification in their parameter because they came form `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
        
        Collection<User> findByTypeIn(Collection<String> types, Pageable pageable);
//      omit methods which have Specification here they are already defined in JpaSpecificationExecutor interface 
}
```

There is no problem in your situation because you can include your `In` operator  inside `Specification`  I don't elaborate more on how to do that because there is already a good answer here for this specific situation:

[Add WHERE IN clause to JPA Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959816/add-where-in-clause-to-jpa-specification)

that link would solve your problem, however If you want to read more about `JpaSpecificationExecutor`  you can read the following link for more detail:

[spring data jpa specification](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-specifications?amp)

Comment: Can you show me little more which lines I need to change, please?

Comment: I have elaborated more about that, hope that would help.